# Time conversion confusion

Tags: .net, timezone

Observe the following simple code in C#:

```
var tziCentral = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
var dtCentral = new DateTime(2014, 7, 28, 1, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
var dtUTC = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dtCentral, tziCentral);
Console.WriteLine("{0} CST is {1} UTC", dtCentral, dtUTC);
```

The output is:

```
7/28/2014 1:00:00 AM CST is 7/28/2014 6:00:00 AM UTC
```

Which gives us 5 hours difference.

Next, go to http://www.timebie.com/timezone/utccst.php. According to that site the difference should be 6 hours.

However, according to http://www.worldtimebuddy.com/cst-to-utc-converter the difference is 5 hours, if GMT is UTC.

I am confused.

What is the right answer?

Comment: Note that `"Central Standard Time"` in your code is the `Id` of the Windows time zone.  It covers *both* Central Standard Time and Central Daylight Time.  A better name would be `"Central Time"`, but alas, the identifiers are fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is due to the difference between CDT and CST, CDT being Central Daylight Time. 5 hours is the correct answer.